# Java3D drawing empty white window in an applet

Tags: java, applet, java-3d

i am learning java3D 1.5.2 and already done some ColorCube testing. The last java3D applet i done is about 2000 ColorCubes rotating, translating in both themselves and whole universe. The cubes are generated as a leaf-node-array of the transform branch group

Picture:
[image]

My problem is: sometimes it shows well without any problem but sometimes  window is white and nothing shows until i resize the window or make it full-screen.

**Question:** Can you give me some hints about this problem? I am not using any repaint() or similar methods. Java3D thread is drawing whole thing i assume. How can i overcome this drawing-update problem?

Here is a short pseude-code:

```
class myclass extends Applet
{
    public void init()
        {
           //some init here
        }

    public void start()
        {
           //i make my thread start here
           mythread.start();
        }

    public void stop()
        {
           //...i make my thread pause here
        }

    public void destroy()
        {
           // Here i release the thread
        }

    public void paint()
        {
           //nothing here. its empty
        }

    public class my_thread extends Thread
        {
            public void run()
                 {
                        //here i use the java3D to initialize java3D things
                        while(working)
                           {
                               // here i change 2000 colorcubes' displacement and rotation
                           }
                 }
        } 
}
```

Here is some of the initialisation of java3D i mentioned:

```
            GraphicsConfiguration GC_me=SimpleUniverse.getPreferredConfiguration();
            Canvas3D Canvas_me=new Canvas3D(GC_me);
            SimpleUniverse Space_me = new SimpleUniverse(Canvas_me);
```

Thanks.

Here is a full code:

```
package fiziksel_model;


import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;

import javax.media.j3d.*;
import javax.vecmath.*;

import com.sun.j3d.utils.*;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.geometry.ColorCube;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.SimpleUniverse;


public class yabanci extends Applet{

/**
* Version 1
*/


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;



public drawer_thread palette=new drawer_thread();
int i;
public void init()
{
   System.out.println(" started! ");



}
//Geometry geom;
public void start()
{
   System.out.println(" continuing...");


   palette.start();


}
public void stop()
{
   System.out.println(" stopped! ");

}
public void destroy()
{
   System.out.println(" destroyed!");

}
public void paint(Graphics g)
{

           System.out.println(" painted! ");// does not print anything.
}


public class drawer_thread extends Thread
{

   public void run()
   {
       Vector3f temp_vect=new Vector3f();
       ColorCube color_box=new ColorCube(0.2f);

       GraphicsConfiguration GC_me=SimpleUniverse.getPreferredConfiguration();
       Canvas3D Canvas_me=new Canvas3D(GC_me);
       SimpleUniverse my_space = new SimpleUniverse(Canvas_me);

       BranchGroup cube_barrage = new BranchGroup();
       Transform3D rotator_element=new Transform3D();
       Transform3D temp_rotator=new Transform3D();


       cube_barrage.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
       cube_barrage.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_READ);
       cube_barrage.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_CHILDREN_READ);
       cube_barrage.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_CHILDREN_WRITE);
       setLayout(new BorderLayout());




       TransformGroup rotator1=new TransformGroup(rotator_element);
       TransformGroup rotator2=new TransformGroup(rotator_element);
       TransformGroup rotator3=new TransformGroup(rotator_element);
       TransformGroup rotator4=new TransformGroup(rotator_element);

       Vector3f translation[]=new Vector3f[4000];
       TransformGroup core1[]=new TransformGroup[4000];
       TransformGroup core2[]=new TransformGroup[4000];
       TransformGroup core3[]=new TransformGroup[4000];
       Transform3D core_move1[]=new Transform3D[4000];
       Transform3D core_move2[]=new Transform3D[4000];
       Transform3D core_move3[]=new Transform3D[4000];
       for(int j=0;j<4000;j++)
       {
       translation[j]=new Vector3f();
       core1[j]=new TransformGroup();core2[j]=new TransformGroup();
       core_move1[j]=new Transform3D();
       core_move2[j]=new Transform3D();    
       core_move3[j]=new Transform3D();
       }

       for(int j=0;j<4000;j++)
       {
       translation[j]=new Vector3f();
       translation[j].x=(float) (j/10.0);
       translation[j].y=(float)(-0.5+Math.random()*1.0);
       translation[j].z=(float)(-0.5+Math.random()*1.0);

       core_move1[j].setTranslation(translation[j]);
       core_move2[j].setTranslation(translation[j]);
       core_move3[j].setTranslation(translation[j]);

       core1[j]=new TransformGroup(core_move1[j]);
       core2[j]=new TransformGroup(core_move1[j]);
       core3[j]=new TransformGroup(core_move1[j]);
       core1[j].setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
       core1[j].setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_READ);
       core2[j].setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
       core2[j].setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_READ);

       core3[j].setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
       core3[j].setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_READ);
       }






       rotator1.addChild(rotator2);
       rotator2.addChild(rotator3);rotator3.addChild(rotator4);
       rotator1.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
       rotator1.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_READ);
       rotator2.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
       rotator2.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_READ);
       rotator3.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
       rotator3.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_READ);
       rotator4.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
       rotator4.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_READ);




       for(int j=0;j<4000;j++)
       {
            rotator4.addChild(core1[j]);
            core1[j].addChild(core2[j]);
            core2[j].addChild(core3[j]);
            core3[j].addChild(new ColorCube(0.1));
       }


       cube_barrage.addChild(rotator1);


       cube_barrage.compile();
       my_space.addBranchGraph(cube_barrage);
       add("Center", Canvas_me);
       //Canvas_me.validate();

       my_space.getViewingPlatform().setNominalViewingTransform();
       float ran[]=new float [4000];
       float ran2[]=new float [4000];
       Vector3f temp_vector=new Vector3f();
       for(int j=0;j<4000;j++)
       {
           ran[j]=(float) Math.random();
           ran2[j]=(float) Math.random();
       }

       for(i=0;i<10000;i++)
       {



           rotator1.getTransform(temp_rotator);
           temp_rotator.setScale(0.1+0.05*Math.abs(Math.sin(i*0.03)));
           rotator1.setTransform(temp_rotator);

           rotator2.getTransform(temp_rotator);
           temp_rotator.rotX(i*0.03);
           rotator2.setTransform(temp_rotator);

           rotator3.getTransform(temp_rotator);
           temp_rotator.rotY(i*0.03);
           rotator3.setTransform(temp_rotator);

           rotator4.getTransform(temp_rotator);
           temp_rotator.rotZ(i*0.03);
           rotator4.setTransform(temp_rotator);


           for(int j=0;j<4000;j++)
           {
               core1[j].getTransform(temp_rotator);
               temp_rotator.get(temp_vector);
               temp_vector.x+=(float) (-0.5+Math.random())*0.02;
               temp_vector.y+=(float) (-0.5+Math.random())*0.02;
               temp_vector.z+=(float) (-0.5+Math.random())*0.02;

               temp_rotator.setTranslation(temp_vector);
               core1[j].setTransform(temp_rotator);

               core2[j].getTransform(temp_rotator);


               temp_rotator.rotZ(i*0.03+0.01*ran[j]*i);

               core2[j].setTransform(temp_rotator);


               core2[j].getTransform(temp_rotator);
               temp_rotator.rotY(i*0.02+0.01*ran2[j]*i);
               core2[j].setTransform(temp_rotator);
           }


           System.out.println(i);
           try {
               sleep(40);
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   }}}
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What output is in the Java Console?

Comment: Java console output is just writing "applet stopped" "applet active" "applet destroyed". There is no error of any type in console.

Comment: Im not getting any error. Its about getting a white window instead of getting some colored cubes(and this is %50 of the trials)

Comment: Thanks for the update.. BTW - Given `public void paint(Graphics g)
{

            System.out.println(" yeniden çizildi");
}` this applet should never paint anything.  Don't override `paint()` unless you intend to paint something.  Of course that does not explain the inconsistent behavior seen.  What make and version of the JRE is running on that machine?

Comment: Machine? Are you mentioning language i am using? Java jre7 (latest Eclipse. I think it is Indigo)

Comment: *"Here is a full code but its in my native language."*  I feel that code in a language I do not understand is easier to debug than code snippets in any language.

Comment: Okay i am changing the native to English. Will take some time im sorry.

Comment: Please ignore my comments about language.  They were not closely related to fixing the problem. -- Back to fixing the problem..  I need specifics for JRE  make/model follow [this link](http://pscode.org/prop/?prop=java.vendor%2Cjava.version&format=TSV) and copy/paste the result that appears in the text field on the page.

Comment: About the `paint(Graphics)` method.  I guess you were debugging it with the `println(..)` to check it was being called.  But don't override `paint()` for this test.  Remove that entire method.

Comment: Ok guys, i changed it to English and here is my jre: Name Value
java.vendor Oracle Corporation
java.version 1.7.0_05

Comment: I also removed the entire paint but did not solve the problem. Anyway, thank you for your time

Comment: Maybe it is a bug in that JRE.  Try a different micro-version (e.g. 1.7.0_04).  Is the applet available at an URL we can visit it?  What is the URL?

Comment: Okay, i dont know how to publich my applet. I am looking for it.

Comment: Do you know any host sites to publish my applets?

Comment: Ok, i screwed my java while installing another without uninstalling the old one.

Comment: I put a picture. Hope it stimulates us to give an answer. ^^

Comment: Java 3D is pretty outdated; it hasn't been updated for years. Please use something more modern like JMonkeyEngine or Ardor3D.

Comment: @Oskar: are Jmonkey and Ardor as easy as java3D or harder? I mean are they tree-structure like SimpleUniverse?

Comment: If you're looking for a library that's similar to Java 3D, I would suggest Xith3D.

Comment: @Oskar: i just installed 3 .jar files to start using java3D, i wish Xith3D is not harder.

Comment: Since February 10, 2012, Java 3D uses JOGL 2.0 for its hardware accelerated OpenGL rendering, the port has been initiated by Julien Gouesse.------>Does this mean java3D outdated?

Comment: don't you have some sort of OutOfMemoryException or stack trace of any kind? also could you correct your full code, some variables are missing or mispelled

Comment: Not even a single exception. Also i dont know where problem could be.

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık well if I just copy past your code in eclipse, it can't find gecici_donu or kup for example. I also see that you translated from native to english, could you re edit with the native snippet? i could easily refactor from that

Comment: Okay everybody, i copied and pasted fully-working code from my eclipse project.

Comment: Make it full-screen after it starts counting in console-output. Otherwise it gets stuck too. But this is not the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Second try : Move following lines of code from your thread into the applet's init method to ensure that they run in the event dispatching thread (EDT).

```
private SimpleUniverse my_space = null;
public void init()
{
   System.out.println(" started! ");
   GraphicsConfiguration GC_me = SimpleUniverse.getPreferredConfiguration();
   Canvas3D Canvas_me = new Canvas3D(GC_me);
   my_space = new SimpleUniverse(Canvas_me);
   setLayout(new BorderLayout());
   add("Center", Canvas_me);
}
```

Please, save your 200 reputation as I'm not registered. When do i register i dont know.

Comment: So, init() is really an initialization :)  Could be in conjunction with constructor.

Comment: See also [*Initial Threads*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) and [*How does the bounty system work?*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/163188)

Answer (score 3):

Give this a try:
Set the system properties "sun.awt.noerasebackground" and "sun.awt.erasebackgroundonresize" to true in your applet launching code.